When I try to build the app on CMD using Cordova(cordova build android)
I'm new to this, been using cordova for convert web app do mobile app
How do I fix this problem, I've installed already installed the build tool 34.0.0. and the latest 36.0.0-rc1 and tried using different ver. of gradle
This is my system variables
This is the Path
C:\App\OS>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Clark\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\App\OS\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 73

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 34.0.0.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\App\OS    if (highestBuildToolsVersion.isLowerThan(minBuildToolsVersionString)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("""
            No usable Android build tools found. Highest ${minBuildToolsVersion.getMajor()}.x installed version is
            ${highestBuildToolsVersion.getOriginalString()}; Recommended version
            is ${minBuildToolsVersionString}.
        """.replaceAll(/\s+/, ' ').trim())
    }\platforms\android\tools\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug

This is the line 73 in cordova.gradle
    if (highestBuildToolsVersion.isLowerThan(minBuildToolsVersionString)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("""
            No usable Android build tools found. Highest ${minBuildToolsVersion.getMajor()}.x installed version is
            ${highestBuildToolsVersion.getOriginalString()}; Recommended version
            is ${minBuildToolsVersionString}.
        """.replaceAll(/\s+/, ' ').trim())
    }


Welcome to SO! What does cordova requirements show? Are your build tools on the PATH and/or maybe you have to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and/or ANDROID_HOME?

IDK how to check Cordova req. but I installed all the latest tools and stuff.  Yes I seth the path and System variables you can check it at the link I provide at This is my system variables and This is the Path.
